# How do I append DOM-elements to dynamically newly added DOM-elements

Tags: jquery, dom, append

A dropdown menu is dynamically added to the DOM via click on a hamburgerbutton. I'd like to dynamically append some content to this dynamically created dropdown menu.

I tried the append method. As expected this doesn't work because the dropdownmenu is not existing at the time the code is executed.

```
$(".dynamicallyaddeddropdownmenu").append("some content");
```

I also tried:

```
$(document).on("focus", ".dynamicallyaddeddropdownmenu", function(){
    $(".dynamicallyaddeddropdownmenu").append("some content");
});
```

`CSS::after` wouldn't work, because the added content has to be clickable.

Comment: You need to provide more context, or a working example of the issue.  The second snippet will work, provided your element can be focused upon.

Comment: try to use the append function right after the code that creates the dynamic element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let say you have html, which on button click generates dynamic dropdown:

```js
$('#btn').click(function () {
        if ($('.dynamicallyaddeddropdownmenu').length == 0) {
        $('#div1').append('<select class="dynamicallyaddeddropdownmenu"></select>');
        AppendInDropdown();
    }
    });
    function AppendInDropdown() {
        $('.dynamicallyaddeddropdownmenu').focus(function () {
            $(".dynamicallyaddeddropdownmenu").append('<option value="1">1</option>'); //append some content
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<br />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me" />
```

you need to invoke AppendInDropdown() function when you dynamically add the dropdown

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that! Thx!

Answer (score -1):

I am not a JavaScript expert but I had this issue with jQuery before and I remember that it worked when I used `.after()` instead `.append()` with the `.on()` variation for dynamically added items.